# Not getting Library Fields in Reusable Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created Reusable workflow and I have published on Library but I'm not able to get Library columns in workflow

Answer (score 1):

Reusable workflow does not show all list item fields in current item , as it is associated with content type.Because it is generalise for all list in site which has that content type.

If you want to use all fields from your list you can use get data from list with item id.

Comment: I did't get you Sam

Answer (score 0):

Is your workflow associated with your library? Go to the List/Library settings page in SharePoint Designer and make sure your your workflow is listed under workflow section.